# Best way to deal with a stored procedure that's doesn't return any result

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project.I have a stored procedure which inserts a row and doesn't return any result. If I use `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway`, the flow simply terminates and won't connect to the next channel.

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInCallableStatement] CallableStatement.execute() returned 'false'   
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInCallableStatement] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned 0  
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
```

My requirement is to continue the flow even if the stored procedure doesn't return any result. What is the best way to handle?

> UPDATE

After Artem's response, I have configured stored procedure outbound channel adapter in the following manner:

```
<int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="buildRequestBasedDataSource" input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2" output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-publishSubscribeChannel"/>
    <!-- PQPutUserBAInformation Channel -->

        <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-publishSubscribeChannel"  />

        <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter
                        id="PQPutUserBAInformation-AWD-StoredProcedure2" 
                        channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-publishSubscribeChannel" 
                        data-source="routingDataSource" 
                        stored-procedure-name="ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA"
                        ignore-column-meta-data="true"  
                        use-payload-as-parameter-source = "false" >

                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_USERID" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_USERID" expression="#xpath(payload, '//CurrentUserID')" />
        </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter>

        <!-- Service Activator to build the Message from the Stored Procedure ResultSet -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-publishSubscribeChannel" ref="msgHandler" method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />
```

Comment: Duplicate Question. See here. I asked the same thing :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676147/spring-integration-chain-flow-handling-void-gateway-calls/42676419#42676419

Comment: If my stored procedure is failed during the insertion of the record, then I need the error message. So, your question might not help me in that case.

Comment: Are you catching a exception in your stored procedure and swallowing it? You should be able to propagate an oracle exception back to the gateway and then use the error channel. That's what I did for my errors.

Comment: I got your point. I am handling the errors any way. Can you show me how you configured `publish-subscribe-channel` in your case so that I might get some rough idea?

Comment: I was using direct channels. However the spring integration examples github should have plenty of examples for pub sub.  I find it's also good design to return a boolean for update stored proc operations or a integer value in this case representing the number of deletes executed.

Comment: I am still unable to get how to get my task done. Any pseudo code can you share?

Comment: The example above in the first comment has code. Shows the error channel on the gateway to handle the oracle errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use `stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` instead.

To continue the flow after that you should consider to use `publish-subscribe-channel` as an input for that adapter. And make one more subscriber to go ahead in the stream.

Another way to achieve the same behavior is `recipient-list-router`.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. I was on vacation all these days. I have added `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` and `int:publish-subscribe-channel`, but I am getting exception,  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An output channel was provided, but the final handler in the chain does not implement the MessageProducer interface.`

Comment: You didn't tell us that you use `chain`. Of course you have to break it if you are going to use Outbound channel adapter

Comment: I apologize for not telling you that I am using `chain` component. How to specify input and output channels for `stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter`. I am using it for the first time.Could you please share one example? One more thing I forgot to inform you that I might get result(ResultSet) from the stored procedure sometimes and sometimes not.  So, could you please suggest me on how to handle this situation?

Comment: `outbound-channel-adapter` is one-way. There is no `output`. That is the rule for any `outbound-channel-adapter`. The flow stops here at all. If your procedure returns result sometimes, it is ignored in the `stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter`.

Comment: You can find some samples about Stored Procedures here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have added my code to the question after configuring the stored procedure outbound channel adapter. Does that make sense to you? Please let me know if I configured in a wrong way.

Comment: Your mistake that you duplicate `PQPutUserBAInformation-AWD-StoredProcedure2` ID for the `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter>` and then for the `<int:publish-subscribe-channel>`. And it isn't clear why you use `channel="buildRequest"` as an id from the `<service-activator>` above. All the config in a mess. It isn't surprise that it doesn't work. Please, follow those samples for proper configuration.

Comment: I couldn't find any sample that uses stored procedure outbound channel adapter in the link that you have shared.

Comment: I am sorry that I have  configured wrongly earlier. I have updated  the modified configuration to the question. Does this configuration makes some sense? . I am able to hit the stored procedure now. But I just want to make sure that I configured correctly.

Comment: Yes! Now it's good. And your "process after procedure" via `publish-subscribe-channel` and the second subscriber is correct, too. Bare in mind the same message will be sent to that second ` <int:service-activator>`, that has been sent to the stored-proc adapter. That is nature of the `publish-subscribe-channel`. See more info in the EIP Book and Spring Integration Reference Manual.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I think it would be good if one sample for stored procedure outbound channel adapter included in the link that you have shared.